# How does the LED stumps help in Cricket?

Tags: cricket, equipment, wicket

In recent matches I can see that LED stumps are used in twenty twenty world cup. Heard that it is very costly. Why do they use that? Does it help for anything or only for fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first tell you that it is not for fun.

It is a new technology which was first tested and used in the [KFC Big Bash League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bash_League) in Australia. The main purpose of using it is, it will help the 3rd umpire to give the right decision for close calls when it comes to run out or stumping.

The LED light flashes only when the bail is completely dislodged from the stumps which means the 3rd umpire can get a clear view whether the bails are dislodged completely or not. On the basis of light flash he can make the decision so that the probability of making wrong decisions will reduce drastically.

Answer (score 2):

When the LED stumps were first used in the Big Bash League, its Senior Manager had this to say:

> "These light up stumps are all about enhancing the spectator
>   experience during BBL matches and ensuring that the BBL remains highly
>   entertaining for the fans," BBL Senior Manager Anthony Everard said in
>   a statement.
>
> "The stumps do not have any effect on the playing conditions nor will
>   they be used in any part for umpire decisions," he added.

Without doubt, it will definitely help the umpires but the management didn't place those fancy toys for that purpose in the first place. But today, when it's being used in an ICC event, it looks like it may be serving its implicit purpose: helping an umpire in trouble.

[Source](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/cricket/flashing-wickets-latest-innovation-in-twenty20-sees-stumps-light-up-8393130.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest innovation in cricket which is invented by Bronte EcKermann. These high-tech stumps are called as *Zings*. The entire set-up during a match costs US$ 40,000. The main purpose of the LED stumps is to help the third umpire for decisions of stump outs and run outs.

From [this article](http://www.rediff.com/cricket/report/slide-show-1-mahendra-singh-dhoni-to-get-souvenir-led-stumps-only-if-india-win-icc-world-t20-cricket/20140326.htm):

> "The idea was to make it touch friendly. The light might not glow if someone tries to hit with a hammer but if the wicketkeeper touches the bail with ball in his gloves and even a feather touches, it would. **It would make the decisions easier for the third umpire as to what exactly was impact when bail was dislodged from the stumps**."

Other than this, it enhances the spectator experience during the match not only for the spectator at the match but also those watching in broadcast.

---

<sup>* Source: http://indianexpress.com/article/sports/cricket/zing-thing-40k-glowing-stumps-to-add-glitter-to-world-t20/</sup>