# Is it allowed to take the LED stumps to home after winning the match?

Tags: cricket, equipment, wicket, cricket-world-cup

Is it permitted for a player to take the LED stumps or at least bails to home after winning the match at least in the final?

I heard it costs  Rs. 25 lakhs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in [my previous answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4343/540), Zings, the new high-tech LED stumps, are very costly. The entire set-up during a match costs US$ 40,000. That's why Bronte EcKermann, the inventor of Zings doesn't allow players to uproot them after winning the match. He also denied to take them even after winning the final.

But as an exception he said that he will allow MS Dhoni, the captain of the Indian Cricket team, to take the stumps only if India win the T20 World Cup 2014:

> "Well, this is a very costly system. The entire set-up during a match costs US$ 40,000 (Rs 25 lakh approx), so I don't allow the players to uproot it during any celebrations. But I know Dhoni loves keeping a souvenir stump. **If India can win the final, I might get into some arrangement with Dhoni," EcKermann, the inventor of LED stumps**, said.

[Source](http://www.rediff.com/cricket/report/slide-show-1-mahendra-singh-dhoni-to-get-souvenir-led-stumps-only-if-india-win-icc-world-t20-cricket/20140326.htm)

Comment: But, the srilankan players took all the LED stumps.;(